# Alternative to window.open that doesn't involve CORS

Tags: javascript, html, same-origin-policy

I have a page with a list of links that were set to open in new windows/tabs with target='_blank' and I wanted to give users a choice to load links in the same window so I've set up a checkbox to toggle the 'newwin' boolean and now open links with the following function

```
function dolink(myurl) {
if (newwin) { window.open(myurl, '_blank').focus(); }
else { window.open(myurl, '_self'); }
}
```

It works as expected but sets off all sorts of CORS stupidity now. In the first case it prints a message to the console that 'Storage access automatically granted for origin “NEWSITE” on “MYSITE”' which is bad enough and in the second case it stops resources loading on the new site due to CORS restrictions. Is there a better way to do this? I don't want to join these sites to mine, just link to them.

Comment: Use `a` tag instead? Change the `target` attribute of `a` according to `newwin`.

Comment: Perfect! Did you wanna put that in an answer and have it accepted? Otherwise, I could answer it myself and credit you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `a` tag instead. Change the `target` attribute of `a` according to `newwin`.

Comment: If anyone cares the function now looks like 
`function dolink(myurlnk) {`
`if (newwin) { myurlnk.target = "_blank"; }`
`}`
And is called from the link `<a onclick="dolink(this)">`